# Java Observer Pattern for Range-Based Wireless Sensor Network (WSN) Localization

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm building a simulation of range-based Wireless Sensor Network Localization (WSN). A range-based WSN consists of sensors those measure distances. Technical details of the sensors are not important at this stage.

Sensors have two states: *localized* and *unlocalized*.

I need to implement an observer pattern for the following reason:

A sensor has neighbors, i.e. other sensors within its range. Whenever it is localized, it has to broadcast its position to its neighbors. 
Notice that, this is a recursive operation.
If any of its neighbors are localized, it will broadcast its position as well.

A sensor can be localized if and only if it can determine its position using distances from three localized neighbors.

I have two questions:

1) Should I implement `Sensor` class as

```
public class Sensor extends Observable implements Observer
```

2) If so, how can I simulate the `boradcast()` function?

So far I've tried:

```
void broadcastPosition()
{
    for(Sensor s : neighbors)
        s.neighborLocalized(this);
}

void neighborLocalized(Sensor s)
{
    if(!neighborList.contains(s))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is not a neighbor");
    localizedNeighbors.add(s);
    if(localizeSelf()) \\ returns true if the sensor is able to localize itself
        broadcastPosition();
}
```

however, this approach fails because it goes into an infinite loop.

Maybe I should use `wait()` and `notify()`.

To sum up, I have a design problem and I seek your help to solve this.

I send a screenshot of the algorithm presented in the paper of Aspnes et al. 2008

[image]

Comment: A sensor localizes itself and broadcasts its position and receives its own message and in neighborLocalized method broadcasts the message again and you are in a loop. Did I get it right?

Comment: @brifbraff Precisely. You got it absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 things:

1- Give an id to all your sensors and put it in the boroadcast message. When you receive a message check the sender id and if it is your own id ignore the message.

or

2- Keep a member in sensor class something like bool mAlreadyLocalized. First time you are localized set it true and broadcast. Next time you get a message check if you already broadcast when you are localized, and if you did, don't broadcast again.

```
if(localizeSelf() && !mAlreadyLocalized) 
        broadcastPosition();
```